# Is it possible to precompile a Go project and run on different Linux distros

Tags: go, compilation

I'm new to Go, and wonder if I can build my application on my computer, then put on target machines with different Linux systems and run without having to compile it or its dependencies?

How do I figure out on what target systems what binaries can run?

Answer (score 2):

Note that Go binaries compiled on a Linux OS would work on other Linux distro.

If Docker is an option, you can consider using one of the Go Docker images on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/). You can either create a Dockerfile based on one of the `<go-version>-onbuild` images or build your application on your computer, then `COPY` the binary over to one the images that is based off the Linux distro of your choice.

The `onbuild` images builds and runs your application. You can check out its Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/2372c8cafe9cc958bade33ad0b8b54de8869c21f/1.7/onbuild/Dockerfile). I have seen team uses the second approach of building and running the application binary separately in golang-alpine Docker containers to reduce the size of production images.

Otherwise, you can use Go built-in [cross-compilation support](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5), which boils down to:

1. Setting the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` environmental variables to be the values for the target operating system and architecture.
2. Run `go build -v YOURPACKAGE`

Refer [here](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment) for a list of supported `GOOS` and `GOARCH` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the go program on a Linux machine, it should just work elsewhere, if you mark it as executable `chmod +x /path/to/main.go`.

You can specify the build using `env` and the `go build` cmd tool which architecture to build for (or which OS), for example:

```
env GOARCH=arm go build main.go
```

If you want, you can specify Linux with

```
env GOOS=linux go build main.go
```

Note, these are the *target* environments:

> Note that $GOARCH and $GOOS identify the target environment, not the environment you are running on. In effect, you are always cross-compiling. By architecture, we mean the kind of binaries that the target environment can run: an x86-64 system running a 32-bit-only operating system must set GOARCH to 386, not amd64.

see here for a full list of distros and architectures:
https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment